# How to Summarize Lua Unit Test Results?

Tags: bash, unit-testing, lua

I have a script that runs my Lua Unit Test. Each test has its own output of a summary. However, I want to count and see which test fail after all of the test are ran.

The script loops through the test like so:

```
# Loop over all the UTs and run them
for utLuaScript in `ls ut*.lua` ; do
    echo "LAUNCH TEST: ${utLuaScript}"
    lua ./${utLuaScript} -v
    echo
done
```

What is the solution here? Have the number of successes and failure saved to file, then once outside of this loop, go through the file and summarize all of the test. Can the script spit out a variable? What is best practice?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way this is done is with a test runner script. In this approach, the unit tests are not executable by themselves (i.e. `lua ut_foo.lua` doesn't do anything), but must be run through the test runner. For example, `lua test_runner.lua` might run all the tests, and `lua test_runner.lua ut_foo.lua` might run just the "ut_foo" tests. The test runner script takes care of formatting and displaying the test results.

There are quite a few test runners already available for Lua; see the [overview on the Lua-users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/UnitTesting). Perhaps one of those will meet your needs, or can be adapted to do so.

Comment: I understand that, however, I am running more than one lua file. So each file has around 12 or so test within each. I want to summarize everything after running all of the test.

Comment: Yes, I got that - when I said "`lua test_runner.lua` might run all the tests" I meant all the tests in all of the test files. I might be able to give you some more advice if you post an example of how your test files look. (In particular, how they print out test results and what value(s) they return.)